# How to transpose a column to set 2 default values in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I wanted to check for a default value in one of the column and populate the column with 2 default values where the that particular column should be transposed into 2 rows with those 2 default values. Can someone please let me know on how to achieve this bigquery?

my condition is as below,

TABLE STRUCTURE :

```
CREATE TABLE db.QUESTIONS
(
  qst_no string,
  qst_val string
);
```

LOGIC -
IF QST_NO = '100' THEN TRANSPOSE qst_val INTO 2 ROWS AS 'Y' , 'N' ELSE QST_NO

query i tried:-

```
SELECT QST_NO, CASE WHEN QST_NO = '100' THEN 'Y','N' ELSE QST_NO END AS QST_VAL 
FROM DB.QUESTIONS;
```

HOW I WANTED THE DATA TO LOOK LIKE:-

```
QST_NO  QST_VAL
------  ------
100      Y
100      N
101      101
102      102
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output ? also add the query you tried so far

Comment: EDITED. can you please help me out ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can join your table with a dataset containing *(100, 'Y'), (100, 'N')* to split your rows with value 100 into two separate rows :

```
SELECT q.QST_NO, COALESCE(s.QST_VAL, q.QST_VAL) AS QST_VAL
FROM QUESTIONS q
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 100  AS QST_NO,   'Y' AS QST_VAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 100, 'N'
) AS s ON s.QST_NO = q.QST_NO;
```

For this dataset :

```
QST_NO  QST_VAL
------  ------
100      100
101      101
102      102
```

Will results :

```
QST_NO  QST_VAL
------  ------
100      Y
100      N
101      101
102      102
```

Answer (score 0):

See example below

```
with test_data as (
  select '100' QST_NO, '100' QST_VAL union all
  select '101', '101' union all
  select '102', '102' 
)
select QST_NO, QST_VAL from test_data,
unnest(case when QST_NO = '100' then ['Y','N'] else [QST_NO] end) QST_VAL
```

with output

[image]